# Does Clay Golem attack rating matter?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've always wondered whether my Clay Golem actually performs his slow ability on bosses, since they have high defense and I can't really make out whether he is hitting or not.

If he doesn't, would a higher attack rating help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attack rating does indeed matter, and against many enemies, it might be difficult for some of your minions to hit them. This is why many Necromancers spam Skeletal Mages instead of bothering with melee warriors. If you have the proper buffs and curses in place, however, this can be counter-acted. Iron Golems are also much better at hitting their targets because they take on magical properties of the weapons you make them from, so if you're truly having issues you can find a weapon with additional attack rating.

It is basically a trade-off between having a lot of Mages and therefore be able to use your mana for things other than cursing enemies with defense debuffs so that your melee minions can hit them, versus having the extra durability and protection (melee minions will actually get close to the enemy, ensuring their aggro is drawn and be a physical barrier inbetween you and them) of a front line.

Comment: Of course Iron Golems' thorns is also guaranteed (physical) damage, provided the enemy does not have immunity.

Comment: @NickWiggill Indeed, although you can also make Iron Golems from a suit of armor which will increase their defense, making them harder to hit ... or, if you pick just the right piece of armor, it'll just increase their thorns damage instead.

Answer (score 2):

The slow effect is also applied when the Clay Golem is hit. So do't worry too much about its own attack rating. [See this Basin wiki article.](http://wiki.theamazonbasin.com/index.php/Clay_Golem)

Answer (score 1):

The Clay Golem's ability does slow down bosses.

From [diablo.wikia.com](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Clay_Golem):

> The Golem's attack also slows down enemies for a certain percent. The slow works on all opponents, including act bosses.

A higher attack rating does help the Clay Golem hit bosses more often.